# How to import sp_core::Pair?

Tags: pallet, runtime, rust, keyring

In my last question, I asked about [how to generate key pair in substrate](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4292/how-to-generate-key-pair-in-pallet-or-on-offchain-work).But it seems that it is hard to do this.So I have to make a conclusion that I can't generate key pair in substrate sadly. But my intuition told me that I was wrong. So if somebody knows the truth about my question，please tell me.

In the course of struggling against the problem,I still puzzled why I can't use sp_core::Pair in my pallet code. Or who can tell me under what conditions I can import this item to my code.Is there some features or attributs that can help me to import sp_core::Pair into my code. I am not very clear with the condition compilation course of runtime especially the influence of cfg feature. Hope to learn this,anything about this is good for me.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to use `sp_core::Pair` in your runtime.

By design, the `Pair` trait (as well as other traits with the `full_crypto` feature) don't support WASM runtimes.

This is because the WASM runtimes will be compiled for `no_std` environments too, which isn't a suitable environment for hash-based functions (like random seed generation).

Comment: Thanky you for explain this to me. But the substrate official website says “A secure, local entropy source for random number generation” in offchain worker. So how can I use this feature to generate randoms or even generate key pair?

Comment: You can try again by asking what you are actually trying to archive. Creating a Pair seems like the solution that you came up with, but its not possible on-chain. Off-chain is something different.